# Как распарсить русские слова, написанные в английской раскладке?

Tags: python-3.x

Как распарсить строку, написанную на русском при английской раскладке клавиатуры? Например, имеем строку `"Dctv ghbdtn"`, что означает `"Всем привет"`.

Comment: Запиши себе в `dict` значение каждой буквы в соответствии с раскладкой(ключ - английская буква, значение - русская), проходись по строке и в новую строку складывай значения. Потом возвращаешь новую строку.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Чтобы раскладку неверную поправить:

```
layout = dict(zip(map(ord, "qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;'zxcvbnm,./`"
                           'QWERTYUIOP{}ASDFGHJKL:"ZXCVBNM<>?~'),
                           "йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбю.ё"
                           'ЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ,Ё'))
print("Dctv Ghbdtn".translate(layout))
# -> Всем Привет
```

Comment: может стоит поменять заголовок вопроса, чтобы люди с поисковиков могли попасть на этот вопрос?

Answer (score 4):

Сначала делаем словарь для перевода из латиницы в кириллицу:

```
lat2cyr = {'q':'й', 'w':'ц', 'e':'у', 'r':'к', 't':'е', 'y':'н', ... }
```

<sub>Есть недостаток: некоторые буквы могут зависит от конкретной клавиатуры, и вообще, не всем кириллическим буквам соответствуют буквы из латиницы (у нас же 33 буквы, а там 26). У меня на Маке так: `\ - ё`, `' - э`, `; - ж`, `, - б`, `. - ю`</sub>

Затем делаем функцию для перевода каждой буквы:

```
def translate(text):
    # чтобы не париться ещё и с большими буквам
    text = text.lower()
    res = ''
    for l in text:
        # если буква есть в словаре
        if l in lat2cyr:
            # сохранить перевод
            res += lat2cyr[l]
        else:
            # иначе сохранить оригинал
            res += l
    return res
```

Описанный способ можно улучшить, если заменять символы только в составе слов, а не одиночные. А если Вы ожидаете, что ляпы с раскладкой будут делать только в приветственных фразах, то можно сделать словарь для нескольких слов, и только их заменять:

```
lat2cyr = {'ghbdtn': 'привет', ...}

def translate(text):
    text = text.lower()
    for word in lat2cyr:
        text = replace(word, lat2cyr[word])
return text
```

Надеюсь, у Вас нет проблемы определить, какой текст нужно так обрабатывать, а какой нет (чтобы ненароком не преобразовать так нормальный английский).

Comment: Твой ответ полезный том плане что буду пользователей разделять по User-Agent.