# Символы " ' ", "," и т.д. не заменяются на соответствующие значения списка

Tags: python-3.x

Скрипт подразумевает замену слов на правильную раскладку, например при написании "ghbdtn" он выведет "привет". Также при вводе "это" о выведет " 'nj ", НО при при вводе " 'nj " выводит " 'то". Тоже самое и " с б/, ". Объясните пожалуйста, почему так.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
alp_eng = str(list('''`1234567890-=qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;'\zxcvbnm,./~!@#$%^&*()_+QWERTYUIOP{}ASDFGHJKL:"|ZXCVBNM<>?'''))
alp_rus = str(list('''ё1234567890-=йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэ\ячсмитьбю.Ё!"№;%:?*()_+ЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭ/ЯЧСМИТЬБЮ,'''))

res = []

x = input("Введите текст: ")

for lit in x:
    if lit in alp_eng:
        i = alp_eng.index(lit)
        res.append(alp_rus[i])
    elif lit in alp_rus:
        i = alp_rus.index(lit)
        res.append(alp_eng[i])

print (''.join(res))


input ()
```

Comment: посмотрите как `str.translate()` используется: [Как распарсить русские слова, написанные в английской раскладке?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/812170/23044)

Answer (score 1):

Зачем же вы здесь

```
alp_eng = str(list('''`1234567890-=qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;'\zxcvbnm,./~!@#$%^&*()_+QWERTYUIOP{}ASDFGHJKL:"|ZXCVBNM<>?'''))
alp_rus = str(list('''ё1234567890-=йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэ\ячсмитьбю.Ё!"№;%:?*()_+ЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭ/ЯЧСМИТЬБЮ,'''))
```

преобразуете строки в списки, чтобы потом опять получить строки? В результате, у вас получается строка вида

```
['ё', '1', '2',...
```

в которой есть квадратные скобки, кавычки, запятые... Из-за этого вся индексация едет. Не делайте так. Оставьте просто строки:

```
alp_eng = '''`1234567890-=qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;'\zxcvbnm,./~!@#$%^&*()_+QWERTYUIOP{}ASDFGHJKL:"|ZXCVBNM<>?'''
alp_rus = '''ё1234567890-=йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэ\ячсмитьбю.Ё!"№;%:?*()_+ЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭ/ЯЧСМИТЬБЮ,'''
```